# derived structs and pointer to self in parent struct

Tags: c++, struct, polymorphism

I have three structs, one "parent" struct which contains properties, and two structs derived from the parent one, in which I only have methods. Essentially the content of the struct is always the same, but I want different implementations of a same method in different situations.

Example code:

```
struct Unit {

    int id;
    Unit* next;
};

struct CUnit: Unit {

    bool some_complicated_condition(); // client impl
};

struct SUnit: Unit {

    bool some_complicated_condition(); // server impl
};

CUnit* get_client_unit_by_id(int id) {

    CUnit* unit = g_client_units;
    
    while (unit) {
    
        if (unit->id == id && unit->some_complicated_condition()) {
            return unit;
        }
        
        unit = unit->next;
    }
    
    return nullptr;
}
```

When compiling this of course, I get the following error:
`error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'Unit *' to 'CUnit *'`
`note: Cast from base to derived requires dynamic_cast or static_cast`

I can cast `unit->next` like this: `(CUnit*)unit->next`, but I'm trying to avoid this if possible. I've searched but couldn't find an answer. Simply because the content of the struct is the same between the two implementations, and I'd like to be able to use them as is without casting.

So I'm wondering, is there any way I can redefine my structs in a way that'd allow this out of the box?

Comment: _"I'm trying to avoid this if possible"_ Why? If you are absolutely certain that `unit->next` really will be a `CUnit`, there's nothing wrong with casting the pointer.

Comment: Maybe the cleanest way is to  do ```operator++``` overload

Comment: @vikAy> commented on the wrong question? :)

Comment: @Brian you're right, and I know that. I'm just trying to not do it, and to be clear, for syntactic reasons only. i.e. I don't want the clutter of the casting in my code, for no technical reason whatsoever.

I have a feeling this just can't be done but thought I'd ask away and see what comes up

Comment: @spectras how come?

Comment: @vikAy that could fix this specific use case, but wouldn't answer what I'm asking really.

Comment: You could add `some_complicated_condition` to the base class as a pure virtual method.  Then you don't need any casts to call it.

Comment: In addition to using polymorphism, I suggest using an `unordered_map` instead of a home made linked list to store your `Unit`s. Finding a unit with a certain id in an `unordered_map` will often be a lot quicker than looping over all elements in a linked list. Note that you also continue to loop even if you've found the unit with the correct id if the complicated condition returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your original question (which no one seems to want to actually answer - instead just giving you *opinions* on how to write your code): Yes, you can do what you want to do, it involves templatizing Unit by the pointer that you want to store in next: https://godbolt.org/z/qrrMfc7PM

Note that this pattern is so common as to have a name: Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, or CRTP. Read all about it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

```
template < class t_TyNext >
struct Unit {

    int id;
    t_TyNext * next;
};

struct CUnit: Unit< CUnit > {

    bool some_complicated_condition(); // client impl
};

struct SUnit: Unit< SUnit > {

    bool some_complicated_condition(); // server impl
};

CUnit* g_client_units;

CUnit* get_client_unit_by_id(int id) {

    CUnit* unit = g_client_units;
    
    while (unit) {
    
        if (unit->id == id && unit->some_complicated_condition()) {
            return unit;
        }
        
        unit = unit->next;
    }
    
    return nullptr;
}
```

However, there could be valid reasons why you don't want to templatize the base Unit struct - it could cause a bunch of code generation that you'd rather not have. In that case I suggest the solution below, which just hides the base class implementation using a tried-and-true technique called "encapsulation". Then instead of accessing members directly (which is poor C++ style *sometimes* depending on context), access the next pointer using a casting accessor. This helps keep the code "clean" as you suggest is your goal.

```
struct Unit {
    int id;
    Unit* next;
};

struct CUnit: protected Unit 
{
    using Unit::id;
    bool some_complicated_condition(); // client impl
    CUnit * GetNext() { return (CUnit *)Unit::next; }
};

struct SUnit: protected Unit {
    using Unit::id;
    bool some_complicated_condition(); // server impl
    SUnit * GetNext() { return (SUnit *)Unit::next; }
};

CUnit* get_client_unit_by_id(int id) {

    CUnit* unit = g_client_units;
    
    while (unit) {
    
        if (unit->id == id && unit->some_complicated_condition()) {
            return unit;
        }
        
        unit = unit->GetNext();
    }
    
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: hey there, thanks for the answer! indeed, most comments were questioning why I'm doing this rather than just answering the question. The provided example is just code stripped out of a lot of context, there's a bunch of good reasons behind what I'm actually trying to do, but nothing that concerns anyone here. your answer looks fine and I feel bad people downvoted you for it, I'll look into your two solutions.

Comment: I think the template solution is almost what I want, but I also need to be able to use the base Unit struct as is, as it represents a "neutral" unit and it contains methods that are gonna be shared between server and client. it's also the struct used in code that is shared between server and client. The second solution works of course, I had thought of this myself, but it's a little annoying. But I might end up going that route in the end.

Comment: I understood that you were just giving a very vague representation of your code and that you'd rather change as little as possible and just wanted to give you the possibilities that I thought of. Good luck.